# what are the main differences between creating a Navigation Heading and creating a Navigation link inside my Quick launch links

Tags: 2013, navigation, configuration, quick-launch, site-settings

I am working on a Team Site collection inside sharepoint enterprise server 2013. now i went to "Site Setting" >> "look and feel" >> "Navigation", and there are two options to add hyper-links inside my Quick Launch navigation links:-

1. Navigation Heading
2. Navigation Links

[image]

but i am not sure what are the main differences between them ?

now i find those based on my experience but could not find any official documentation which talks about this:-

1. i can add child links under Headings, but i can not add Headings under Heading or links under links!!.
2. also lately i realize the following main difference when i save a site as template. now if i use links , then on any new site which is created based on the template, the links will automatically get updated if its related list is renamed or the view it is referencing has been changed.
   so for example if i have a link  inside a new site which is created based on the template, and the Link reference the defualt view for my document library as follow:-

> /Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Then if i rename the Document library, the link title will get updated automatically, also if i create a new list view and i set it as default list view, then the link will automatically get the new list view url,, while in the Heading case it will keep showing the old document library name and the old default view url !!

so can anyone adivce of what are the real differences between Navigation Heading and Navigation link inside my Quick launch links ?? as in my above 2 differences valid ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you are overcomplicating the issue here. Headings are just links that allow other links to be under them, they are also bolder and a bigger font. Links are just plain links of a smaller font and they can be under headings. It's really all there is to it. You can think of headings as the "Category" or "Topic" of links that are under them.

Comment: i am not over-complicating the issue,but i have noted the problem of using Heading inside my site templates.. where for any site which is created using the site template, its Heading will not be updated if the users change the list name or set a new defualt view. also if they create a new list view and remove the old default list view , then the whole Heading link will be referencing a non existing URL...

Comment: while if i use Links instead of Heading then the link Title and link URL will be updated if i rename my list or change the default view of my list inside the site which is created using the site template. i asked this question since but i could not find any official documentation regarding this issue.. so i am still not sure if my understanding of this is 100% correct?

Answer (score 0):

Navigation heading is a static text under which you can assign your navigation links. So if you rename your list or update its default view, there is not effect on Navigation header under which list's navigation link is defined.

Comment: you are talking as if this is the general case which is not 100% correct,, now if you create a new site based on the Team site template, then by defualt you will get a Heading for the document library and this heading will get updated if u rename the list or change its defualt view link... but if i save this site as template and create a new site based on the template then the Heading will be static inside the new site...